# PDP through balana

Tags: xacml, xacml3, xacml2, balana

I have only one policy file for my server, so do not want to use wso for PDP, but instead trying to write my own PDP with "balana", I can see their is a PDP class and also a Policy class, so which class to use and how to load my "policy.xml" file to the PDP.

Answer (score 3):

I think your requirement is you want to customize the PDP. You can create a wrapper on the top of WSO2 balana PDP that will serve your purpose according to your requirement. You can use PDP class. I am not sure how you are using policies . If you are using Balana or balana samples locally in your system you can store your policies in the resource folder. Take a look at this sample provided by Balana.

https://github.com/wso2/commons/tree/master/balana/modules/balana-samples